Redirecting problems with dockerized headless cms (directus) + reverse proxy (nginx) using paths/subfolders
I have a dockerized setup with two containers: nginx and backend (=directus). I want nginx to forward request for example.com/api/ to my backend container, which is almost working. The nginx config file looks like this
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8055/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

When I call example.com/api/ I am getting already responses from my backend (=directus), which forwards me to example.com/api/admin. Fine so far, but the referenced script files in the html of the admin page are not loaded. The files are referenced in the html with <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/some-script-file.js"></script>. The browser tries to open http://example.com/admin/assets/some-script-file.js instead of http://example.com/api/admin/assets/some-script-file.js. I don't understand why the /api/ part of the url gets lost. How can I fix this?

What is the URL of the HTML page that references the js file? ./assets/some-script-file.js is relative to that.

http://example.com/api/admin

When you say the browser tries to open http://example.com/api/admin/assets/some-script-file.js where are you seeing that? Because Nginx will remove /api before sending the request to the backend.

I am debugging the issue with Chrome Inspector. This is what I see: 1) I open http://example.com/api/, which returns 302 with Location = ./admin. 2) browser opens http://example.com/api/admin (200 OK) and in the html I have the referenced js file ( ./assets/some-script-file.js). From my understanding ./ should refer to the url including /api/admin part. Of course nginx maps that to the docker container (= removing /api/ in the background, which should be fine)

I could probably try to fix the issue somehow with sub_filters, but this seems hacky. Is there a better solution?

I could add following to the nginx config (which already works), but again: it seams hacky.
location /admin/ {
proxy_pass http://backend:8055/admin/; ...
}

I solved the problem by using subdomains, so that all relative urls from script scr tags work for that subdomain. Thanks reddit user tschloss for the hint. Note that http://backend:8055/ referes to my backend (=directus) docker container (with container_name "backend" and exposed ports 8055:8055). Also note, that I had to adapt the DNS entries, in ordert to add an A record for api.example.com.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8055/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

